# Minimum spanning tree and Hamiltonian path

Tags: reference-request, approximation, traveling-salesman, minimum-spanning-tree

For a graph $G(V,E)$, under what conditions is a minimum spanning tree  of $G$ equal to a hamiltonian path on $G$?
IS there any body of literature connecting these two?